# Merge main branch to feature branch - TAB found in multiple lines fatal

Tags: git, tabs, git-merge, fatal-error

Developer is going to sync feature branch they is working on with project main branch (main branch as feature branch upstream branch if I understand git wording properly).

Developer conducts sync by merging main branch to feature branch.

Main branch being merged includes (since merge-base commit) modification in huge number of files (this might be irrelevant here).

Merge results in following error "Fatal: TAB has been found in following lines:" up to 20 lines follow presenting line of source. If to verify listed lines of code in code viewer/editor those are indented by tabulator character indeed. In rare cases line starts with hash character then tabulator-based indentation follows.

For every file in merge error message all lines of code not presented in error are indented by whitespaces >> file default indentation: sequence of whitespace.

TAB found error prevents merge from completion. It is not possible to finalize merge.

**Q:** I wonder by which way these TAB-indentation lines of code managed to be present on main branch however they prevent main branch merge to developer's feature branch.  Might it be some common git feature. Rather, a matter of local configuration (repo, git, ..)?

So far developer in mind practically didn't contribute to main branch, neither by committing directly to nor by branch merge, except for one single old feature branch merge which however modified no file from TAB found error message. These are other project contributors who contributed so far to main branch. All developers work in private clones. Integration to main branch takes place in common GitLab project.

Feature branch in mind here has multiple commits yet is already pushed to remote (mentioned GitLab project).

UPDATE If developer searches all areas of git configuration for 'indent' or 'tab' the search results in zero matches. Also grepping .git/hooks for whole error string or sub-string zero matches result.

UPDATE 2: Found config entries of possible relevance:

```
$ git config -l --show-origin
file:/home/xxx/.gitconfig  init.templatedir=bla bla
...
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
...

file:.git/config        core.whitespace=cr-at-eol
...
file:.git/config        pull.rebase=true
file:.git/config        merge.ff=false
...
```

UPDATE 3: Merge fails also if to modify git config to following

```
file:.git/config        core.whitespace=-tab-in-indent,cr-at-eol
```

However, I am not sure if git is checking variable `core.whitespace` also upon merge and commit.

Actually it seems to be merge commit step which fails in shown manner.

Comment: It's `git diff`, or in general the diff-generating code, that notices and complains about whitespace errors as configured via `core.whitespace`. If you don't like the configuration you are using, change it.

Comment: @torek Does this mean `core.whitespace` is not used during `git commit` nor `git merge`? As for 1st point it is not the question if me likes config or not. Rather a question if presented problem has root cause in git local config cause I look for root cause to resolve problem.

Comment: It's definitely not used during `git commit` itself, but if you have hooks that run `git diff` before a commit, the diff that the hook runs will get the error. Merge *can* run a normalization pass: I don't think this will see any `core.whitespace` issues, but I have not tested that. In any case, the point here is really that you should set `core.whitespace` the way *you* want. If you don't like how it is behaving, change the setting.

Comment: If it should be some hook which triggers diff I wonder why my new configuration `file:.git/config        core.whitespace=-tab-in-indent,cr-at-eol`  is not working.

Comment: That, I don't know: `-tab-in-indent` should certainly be turning this off—and the setting in `.git/config` should override any system-provided setting (the normal state is to have this thing off anyway, so your Git installation would have to turn it on). This all makes me wonder if you have a hook set up and are getting this error from something other than Git itself, perhaps. When I did a web search, I found some fancy third-party hooks that do the same sort of thing.

Comment: Is it is a hook to commit message step which checks for tab-indented lines of code yet raising a fatal if any found. Thank you.